# Manipulation of summation index - power series

Tags: calculus, summation, power-series

**Problem**

> Consider the differential equation: $y''+ty'+2y=t^2e^t $
>
> By setting $y(t)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}c_nt^n$ show that the differential equation can be rewritten as
> $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \big((n+2)(n+1)c_{n+2}+(n+2)c_n \big)t^n=\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{t^n}{(n-2)!} $$

**An attempt**

$$y''=\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}c_n(n-1)nt^{n-2}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}c_{n+2}(n+2)(n+1)t^n$$

$$ty'=t\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}c_nnt^{n-1}=t\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}c_{n+1}(n+1)t^n $$

$$2y=2\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}c_nt^n=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}2c_nt^n $$

Combining all these terms on the left hand side gives

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \Bigg[c_{n+2}(n+2)(n+1)+tc_{n+1}(n+1)+2c_n \Bigg]t^n=t^2e^t$$

As you can see, I'm almost getting to the answer, but there are some things that don't match up. I'm also unsure how

$$t^2e^t=\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{t^n}{(n-2)!} $$

Can anyone help me out and perhaps spot if I have made a mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On  the left side observe that $ \sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} nc_nt^{n}$ is same as $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} (n+1)c_{n+1}t^{n+1}$ since $0c_0t^{0}=0$.

[You have to split $(n+2)c_n$ as $nc_n+2c_n$ to see why your answer and the given answer match].

Also, $\sum\limits_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac {t^{n}} {(n-2)!} =t^{2} \sum\limits_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac {t^{n-2}} {(n-2)!}=t^{2} \sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac {t^{n}} {n!}=t^{2}e^{t}$.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm also unsure how
> $$t^2e^t=\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{t^n}{(n-2)!} $$

Basically they just shifted the index:

$$ \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{t^n}{(n-2)!} =\frac{t^2}{0!} + \frac{t^3}{1!} ... +O(t^4) = \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \frac{ t^{i+2} }{i!}$$

> $$ty'=t\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}c_nnt^{n-1}=t\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}c_{n+1}(n+1)t^n $$

Indexing is 'non-ideal' here. If you had rather multiplied it out, then you'd get:

$$ t y' = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n c_n t^n$$

What you did is correct but to get the simplest form it'd be ideal to first multiply and then re-index. Now, put this new quantity into your differential equation and it should give you the answer.